# Microsoft Access 2010 - Updating Multiple Rows with Different values in ONE query

Tags: sql, ms-access, database

I have a question about updating multiple rows with different values in MS Access 2010.

```
Table 1: Food
ID | Favourite Food
1 | Apple
2 | Orange
3 | Pear

Table 2: New
ID | Favourite Food
1 | Watermelon
3 | Cherries
```

Right now, it looks deceptively simple to execute them separately (because this is just an example). But how would I execute a whole lot of them at the same time if I had, say, 500 rows to update out of 1000 records.

So what I want to do is to update the "Food" table based on the new values from the "New" table.

Would appreciate if anyone could give me some direction / syntax so that I can test it out on MS Access 2010. If this requires VBA, do provide some samples of how I should carry this out programmatically, not manually statement-by-statement.

Thank you!

---

ADDENDUM (REAL DATA)

```
Table: Competitors
Columns: CompetitorNo (PK), FirstName, LastName, Score, Ranking

query: FinalScore
Columns: CompetitorNo, Score, Ranking
```

- Note - this query is a query of another query, which in turn, is a query of another query (could there be a potential problem here? There are at least 4 queries before this FinalScore query is derived. Should I post them?)

In the competitors table, all the columns except "Score" and "Ranking" are filled. We would need to take the values from the FinalScore query and insert them into the relevant competitor columns.

---

Addendum (Brief Explanation of Query)

```
Table: Competitors
Columns: CompetitorNo (PK), FirstName, LastName, Score, Ranking
Sample Data: AX1234, Simpson, Danny, <blank initially>, <blank initially>

Table: CompetitionRecord
Columns: EventNo (PK composite), CompetitorNo (PK composite), Timing, Bonus
Sample Data1: E01, AX1234, 14.4, 1
Sample Data2: E01, AB1938, 12.5, 0
Sample Data3: E01, BB1919, 13.0, 2
```

Event No specifies unique event ID
Timing measures the time taken to run 200 metres. The lesser, the better.
Bonus can be given in 3 values (0 - Disqualified, 1 - Normal, 2 - Exceptional). Competitors with Exceptional are given bonus points (5% off their timing).

```
Query: FinalScore
Columns: CompetitorNo (PK), Score, Ranking
```

Score is calculated by wins. For example, in the above event (E01), there are three competitors. The winner of the event is BB1919. Winners get 1 point. Losers don't get any points. Those that are disqualified do not receive any points as well.

This query lists the competitors and their cumulative scores (from a list of many events - E01, E02, E03 etc.) and calculates their ranking in the ranking column everytime the query is executed. (For example, a person who wins the most 200m events would be at the top of this list).

Now, I am required to update the Competitors table with this information. The query is rather complex - with all the grouping, summations, rankings and whatnots. Thus, I had to create multiple queries to achieve the end result.

Comment: Your question is by no means clear. Do you wish to insert the values in table2 into table1? Do you wish to match the ids and add etra columns (not a good idea). If you are new to this, imaginary data is likely to be unhelpful. Real data is nearly always a good idea.

Comment: Yes, I would like to insert values from "New" into "Food".

Comment: The new food table should look like the following: 1-Watermelon, 2-Orange, 3-Cherries.

Comment: Is the `New` table a base table or a `VIEW` ('stored Query object')?

Comment: My bad, @onedaywhen - I had assumed they functioned similarly. "New" is actually a query (this query is composed of many other queries).

Comment: And do those [`VIEW`s involve summarization ('Totals Query')](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/116142) by any chance? BTW you should be forgiven for thinking that an update using a viewed table should be no different from one involving a base table :)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. The queries involve lots of group bys and summarizations. (More info added to original question) :)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
UPDATE Food 
INNER JOIN [New] 
ON Food.ID=New.ID
SET Food.[Favourite Food] = New.[Favourite Food]
```

Comment: Thank you.
Unfortunately, upon executing the statement, I get an error dialog from MS Access. "Operation must use an updateable query."

Comment: Would the error be caused by the fact that I had used a query instead of a table? ([New] = query of another table)

Comment: And that is the problem with imaginary data. Do you have indexes on both ID columns? Are the ID columns unique.

Comment: Our comments crossed. Yes, that could be a problem. What are the details of the query?

Comment: Alright, I shall post my real data underneath my question. Give me a moment - thanks for your help.

Comment: Both ID columns (CompetitorID - as per addendum above) are unique. The table is set as a primary key, although I'm not sure how to do that with a query - both columns are unique, nonetheless.

Comment: I am afraid onedaywhen has given you your answer. You will not be able to update from views (queries) that have total columns in this way. How about you post some sample data from the table that new is obtained from and some notes on what makes a new row and someone, possibly ebven me :) , may come up with a suitable alternative .

Comment: Mm - I've included some more data. Hope this helps in understanding the problem better! :)